# Optimization with both L1 and L2 regularization

Tags: optimization, algorithms, lasso, regularization, matrix-decomposition

After doing some research I suppose the hard part is that, L2 regularized problem is often solved by gradient descent, while L1 regularized problem is often solved by coordinate descent.

But which algorithm should I use when L1 and L2 come up in the same loss function?

My specific problem is to factorize a known matrix $R$ into 3 component:

$ R = P^TAQ $

in which L1 regularization is applied to $A$ for sparsity, while L2 regularization is applied to $P$ and $Q$ for preventing overfitting.

Listing out some algorithms is enough. More detailed explanations are also appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "L1 and L2 come up in the same loss function" ? What is the loss function that you are talking about?

Comment: @Tim I supposed the specific form of loss function is not important so I did not write it out. What I need is a general indication for such kind of problem. "L1 and L2 come up in the same loss function" means the loss function takes the form of $ cost + term_{L1} + term_{L2} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Proximal gradient methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximal_gradient_method) are natural here; the prox operator for $L_1$ is to move each entry a constant difference towards zero, while the one for $L_2$ is to multiply each entry by the relevant amount.

Coordinate descent methods will still work fine too. In this case, you'd solve coordinate-wise for entries of $A$ similar to if you were doing LASSO and for the entries of $P$ and $Q$ as if you were doing ridge regression.